# SQLite get date between two Longs in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this piece of code to return all rows between Long A and Long B

```
public ArrayList<CashGame> getAllCashGamesByDates(Long startdate, Long enddate) {
    ArrayList<CashGame> cashgameList = new ArrayList<CashGame>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.query(TABLE_CASHGAMES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_BUYIN, KEY_RESULT, KEY_START, KEY_END, KEY_LOCATION },      startdate + ">=? AND " + enddate + " <?",
            new String[]{startdate.toString(), enddate.toString()} , null, null, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            CashGame cashgame = new CashGame();
            cashgame.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            cashgame.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            cashgame.setBuyin(cursor.getDouble(2));
            cashgame.setResult(cursor.getDouble(3));
            cashgame.setStartDate(date = new Date(cursor.getLong(4)));
            cashgame.setEndDate(date = new Date(cursor.getLong(5)));
            cashgame.setLocation(cursor.getString(6));
            // Adding contact to list
            cashgameList.add(cashgame);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    // return contact list
    return cashgameList;
}
```

I guess there's something wrong with the query but I didn't found the mistake I made. 
Hope someone sees it!

Comment: What is the outcome right now, and how does it not match what you expect?

Comment: are you getting any error? Any specific reason o thin something wrong?

Comment: No errors but also no results, in my datebase there are two rows which would return in my request it didnt worked.

Comment: I have two longs which I create with this piece of code <br>Date date = new Date(2012,04,01);
  Date date2 = new Date(2012, 05,01);
  
  list = db.getAllCashGamesByDates(date.getTime(), date2.getTime());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume this:

```
... startdate + ">=? AND " + enddate + " <?" ...
```

should be more along:

```
... "startdate>=? AND enddate<?" ...
```

**Edit:**

Not sure how to make sense of your where clause, but perhaps you mean this instead:

```
... "startdate<=? AND enddate>?" ...
```

**Another edit:**

Why not just invoke `cursor.moveToNext()`:

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand your where clause, but have a look at my update.

Comment: `while (cursor.moveToNext())` is preferable since it move the cursor and tests it all at once

Comment: @njzk2: yeah I forgot to move the cursor there... just fixed that; thanks for that; I don't develop with android, but I just have a hard time with 2 levels of indentation for reading a cursor.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: i still don't see the point of calling isAfterLast AND moveToNext. A simple while(cursor.moveToNext()) { // DO stuff } is enough

Comment: @njzk2: sure, but the documentation is at least to me ambiguous about if moveToNext skips over the first record when first invoked; if it does, then your simple while skips the first record... if not, then yes I agree with you 100% http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext()

Comment: @sixfeetsix: I used it several times, it does not skip the first record (basically, when you receive a cursor, isBeforeFirst is true)

Comment: @njzk2: ha ok I found it in the docs: "Returns A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry."; I'll update my answer; thanks for the info.